# Authenticating UserService FROM appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication

Is it possible to somehow log in to UserServices from appengine WITHOUT redirecting the user to the standard login page?

I know you can use ClientLogin from the clientside, but can i use it to log in from a servlet running on appengine?

Lets say i have LoginServlet wich accepts POST-data (user/password), can i use ClientLogin from that servlet to authenticate? 
Or is there perhaps another way.

Thanks

Comment: @Nick Johnson : Maybe he wants to support both authentication mechanism - OAuth and his own auth system.

Comment: @Rudy Then the authentication flow will have to be different in either case - he shouldn't be soliciting users' Google account passwords.

Comment: @Nick : I think he wants to create single entry point of authentication, to make sure users  not getting confused. I believe GAE also supports this.

Comment: @Rudy "Users getting confused" is exactly what happens when you try to explain to them that they should never enter their credentials into a third-party site - oh, except this site, which is nice, we promise.

Comment: @Nick: I believe on term "Single entry Single exit". But since the asker is not here, I believe just let him to explain why he needs that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible and for a good enough reason that the app can literally steal the password. Standard login page is safe way to authenticate and grant permission for an app. You can do things like loading the login page in a frame inside your servlet or customize login page to an extent by changing your app details like name etc.

Comment: Logging in via ClientLogin can steal the password aswell, i dont see the big difference there.. :o)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. I remember that I read it once inside "Google Research of Federated Login UI article".

Check this :

1. [Federated Login Link](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html) under **"Relying Parties - Designing a Scalable Login User Interface"**
2. and this: [UI Guidelines Federated Login](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/summary).